# Export list elements each to it's own page in a multi-paged PDF document

Tags: export, pdf-format

I have a list, `myList`, of let's say 20 (different) objects

```
myList = Table["object", {20}]
```

I know would like to export every single element of `myList` to its own PDF page in a 20-paged PDF document; i.e., `myList[[1]]` comes on page 1, ..., myList[[20]] comes on page 20.

Is this possible in *Mathematica*? I have heard of the `Export` function, of course, but have not seen any way of combining 20 exports in one single document.

Comment: I'd do this in LaTeX: `Export["myList.txt", myList // TeXForm]` and then `\input{mylist.txt}` in a minimal latex document where you can ask latex to control page breaks etc.

Comment: @gpap: Interesting option as well. Can you please elaborate what the options are in LaTeX? One would use the Verbatim or how is possible to change all "{" and "}" of myList to page breaks?

Comment: `TexForm` does that. I would use `longtable.sty` or force bage breaks within latex but seeing as you know exactly where the page breaks need to be `Table[Export["page" <> ToString@i <> ".txt", TeXForm@myList[[i]]], {i,
   Length@myList}]` will export page1.txt, ..., page20.txt. Then you can add these on your tex document using `\input{page1.txt}`...`\input{page20.txt}`. Writing this 20 times may be a bit cumbersome but you can actually make mathematica produce the needed code `StringJoin @@ 
 Table["\\" <> "input{page" <> ToString@i <> ".txt}\n" <> "\\" <> 
   "newpage", {i, Length@myList}]`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7974804/695132 (alternative answer within).

Comment: Mathematica lets you do multi page export for TIFF. You could then use a separate program to convert TIFF to pdf.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Vitally has the same idea, but I thought it would be a hassle to do it manually like that, so let MMA insert the page breaks:

```
myList = Array["object", {20}];
Table[CellPrint[{i, 
   Cell["", "PageBreak", PageBreakBelow -> True]}], {i, myList}]
```

Edit: In response to the comment,

Here we create a new notebook and set the page headers to none. Then we Paste your objects and NotebookWrite page breaks. Finally, we Export the notebook and clean up.

```
myList = Array["object", {20}];
report = CreateDocument[Null, 
   PageHeaders -> {{None, None, None}, {None, None, None}}];
Do[
   Paste[report, i];
   NotebookWrite[report,Cell["", "PageBreak", PageBreakBelow -> True]];
, {i, myList}]
Export["myList.pdf", report];
NotebookClose[report];
Clear[report];
```

Comment: Thanks both Vitaly and Timothy.
The problem with this approach, is that when "Printing as PDF", the name of the document is at the top of each page, and I prefer a way without this. Also, would there be a "Export["nameOfDocument.pdf,%]" way of doing this? Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for the update, Timothy. One question, though: why the use of Paste? Why doesn't "NotebookWrite[ report, Cell[ i ]]"
work? Thanks for all help!

Comment: Why is it, when I change the Do[ ] part in your code above by


    Do[
     (
      NotebookWrite[report, {
         Cell[i],
         Cell[Paste[report, Column@myList[[i]]]],
         Cell["dd", "PageBreak", PageBreakBelow -> True]
         }];
      )
     , {i, Length[myList]}]

that Mathematica output "Null" on every page? Thank you for all help!

Comment: We get a clue by looking at the order of printed cells in the new notebook. The contents of Paste are printed first which means that Paste is executed first. Then Paste returns Null (i.e. the contents of Cell[Paste[...]] become Cell[Null]). Then the NotebookWrite writes the Cell[Null].

As for why Paste instead of NotebookWrite... I don't know, the documentation says Paste does some evaluation on its contents, but NotebookWrite says it is essentially the same as Paste.

Comment: I tried this with 1000 images, 2 image per page and it crashes the frontend, any alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

For a few objects on the page a manual approach is

**Top Menu >> Insert >> Page Break**

And then to make sure (on Mac):

**Top Menu >> File >> Print >> PDF >> Open PDF in Preview**

[image]