# Merge pdfs to one

Tags: pdf-format

I have a set of pdfs in a folder, named: 1.pdf,2.pdf,3.pdf,...,20.pdf

Is it possible for mathematica to merge them to one pdf ?
If yes, how ?

I had a look at this answer, but I don't really understand how to use it for my case:
[Combine multiple PDF files into one document](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13251/combine-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-document)

This is what I tried:
I import the PDS:

```
pages = Import[ToString[#] <> ".pdf"] & /@ Range[20];
```

Then I use the code provided in the linked question:

```
Export["test.pdf", 
 CreateDocument[
  Riffle[Join[pages, pages], 
   Cell["", "PageBreak", PageBreakBelow -> True]], Visible -> False]]
```

but the result is that the "comma" is still visible next to each pdf and the pdf pages have been shrinked down by quiet a lot. ... and instead of being 20 pages, it is now 40 pages, each pdf page was printed twice.

[image]

Comment: This feels like one of those cases where you should be using something else (e.g. `pdftk`).

Comment: @Kuba Please have a look at my updated question

Comment: `Riffle[ Join @@ pages, Cell["", "PageBreak", PageBreakBelow -> True]`. Notice that original `pages` were from one pdf, you have an array.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks ! Now its 20 pages ! But it is still shrinked down, like in the image.

Comment: you may try the accepted solution at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31780/export-list-elements-each-to-its-own-page-in-a-multi-paged-pdf-document, where the `myList` variable should be `Flatten[pages]` here