# Import and merge PDF files

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, pdf-format

I have a folder with several pdf no more than 50, I would like to import them to be disordered and that the output was a single pdf (you can imagine it as a proof of form A and we want to produce form B, where the files are the questions)

```
files = {"file1.pdf", "file2.pdf", "file3.pdf", "file4.pdf", "file5.pdf", 
   "file6.pdf", "file7.pdf", "file8.pdf", "file9.pdf", "file10.pdf", 
   "file11.pdf", "file12.pdf", "file13.pdf", "file14.pdf", "file15.pdf", 
   "file16.pdf", "file17.pdf", "file18.pdf", "file19.pdf", "file20.pdf", 
   "file21.pdf", "file22.pdf", "file23.pdf", "file24.pdf", "file25.pdf"};


Sort[files]
```

the previous order, but as disorderly?

**Edit
How do I import all the files from a c: \ directory?

how do I merge all those files into the same file called file and record it in the same directory as c: \?**

Comment: Do you mean randomly sorted? `RandomSample@files`

Comment: @ Rohit Namjoshi , it works very well that order thanks, now as I do to import the files from the ws directory or obtain the output merged into pdf in the same directory with the name say fileB , I imagine something like that but it does not work  list = FileNames[FileNameJoin[dir, "filename*"]]

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. Are you trying to get a list of all files that match some pattern in a specific directory? If so, to get a list of all files with the `pdf` extension in directory `dir`: `FileNames["*.pdf", dir]`

Comment: I explain to you with 3 files for example, file1.pdf, file2.pdf, file3.pdf housed in c: \ ws, I need to import them, undo them and merge them into a single file called fileB, and this fileB (file1.pdf + file2.pdf + disordered file3.pdf) and burn it to the same directory c: \ ws

Comment: *(file1.pdf + file2.pdf + file3.pdf+ disordered )

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "undo them". What is "disordered", some other file?

Comment: I do not think you can do this well in M. This question looks duplicate of [merge-pdfs-to-one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158734/merge-pdfs-to-one) and [combine-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-document](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13251/combine-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-document) so it is better just to use an external tool. There are many such tools to choose from.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi  "undo them" ="disordered"=Random,bad translation sorry, use translator to english

Comment: I second what @Nasser said about using an external tool (like pdftk or ghostscript), however, users may have situations where it is convenient to call it from Mathematica by using `FileNames`, `RandomSample` and `Run`. Sometimes Mathematica is my better shell script...