# Code to generate mandala with message

Tags: graphics, programming, generative-art

A long time ago they gave me many answers to these questions,

[Code that generates a mandala](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136974/code-that-generates-a-mandala)

is it possible to enter text in the center
something like "abcde"  , without the quotes and maybe with some pretty font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the function `MakeMandala` from [this answer by Anton Antonov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136986/125):

```
SeedRandom[123];
Show[MakeMandala[],
 Epilog -> {White, Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.15]], 
   Text[Style["abcd", 
     FontSize -> Scaled[.1], FontFamily -> "Cambria",FontColor -> Red]]}]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[123]; 

Multicolumn[
 Table[Show[MakeMandala[] /. _GrayLevel -> RandomColor[], 
    Background -> Black,
    Epilog -> {Black, Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.15]], 
      Text[Style["abcd", FontSize -> Scaled[.1], 
        FontFamily -> "Cambria", FontColor -> Red]]}],
    10],
 5]
```

[image]

**Update:** ***"how the hollow letters can be placed so that they can be painted"***:

```
SeedRandom[123];
textoutlines = MeshPrimitives[
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
   Text[Style["abcd", 
     FontSize -> 5, FontFamily -> "Cambria", FontColor -> Red]], 
   _Text], 1];

Multicolumn[
 Table[Show[MakeMandala[] /. _GrayLevel -> (rc = RandomColor[]), 
   Background -> Black, 
   Epilog -> {Black, Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.15]], 
      AbsoluteThickness[.5], rc, textoutlines}, 
   ImageSize -> Medium], 4], 2]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** Put a frame on mandalas and export to `PDF`:

```
textoutlines = MeshPrimitives[
   BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
    Text[Style["abcd",
      FontSize -> 5,
      FontFamily -> "Cambria",
       FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.25]]],
    _Text],
   1];

SeedRandom[123];

{rows, columns} = {4, 2};

mandalagrid = Rasterize[Grid@
    Table[Show[MakeMandala[],
      Epilog -> {{White, Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.15]]},
        AbsoluteThickness[.5], textoutlines}, 
      Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, 
      ImagePadding -> 10, ImageSize -> 500],
     rows, columns], 
   ImageResolution -> 400];

Export["mandalagrid.pdf", mandalagrid]
```

> "mandalagrid.pdf"

[image]

Comment: hi , I get this error ,Show::gtype: MakeMandala is not a type of graphics. I have MMA version 13.0 .Is there a way to adapt it for my version?

Comment: @zeros, you need to copy the code for functions `MakeSeedSegment`, `MakeSymmetric` and `MakeMandala` from the linked page.

Comment: It took me a while to integrate it, I haven't worked with MMA for a long time, one last question, how can I add, instead of one line, 2 lines something like  
 abc
defgh  , first line "abc" , second line "defgh" Thanks in advance

Comment: replace `Style["abcd,...]` with  `Style["abc\ndefgh", ...]`

Comment: ,hi , thank ,I forgot to ask how the hollow letters can be placed so that they can be painted

Comment: ,In the end, I did something similar to what you did but with a white background, if you come here, maybe you can help me with two things, like putting a frame on each image and exporting it to pdf to cut them out. Varying some parameters I have achieved several different ones and I managed to insert 8 in a 216mm x 330mm pdf, any ideas how to make several different ones and export them at the same time.
I need them so that some children can entertain themselves by painting them.
Thanks for everything

Comment: zeros, please see update 2.

Comment: ,Thank you very much, it has helped me a lot, I wanted to bother you with the last thing: From the page where the main code originates, there is a code snippet
that allows to make many mandalas all different. Could you implement that in the code you have written for me to generate a pdf with at least 10 pages, with 8 mandalas in each one, all different,code below

Comment: code :n = 12;
Multicolumn@
 MapThread[
  If[#1,
    MakeMandala[MakeSeedSegment[10, #2, #3], #2],
    MakeMandala[MakeSymmetric[MakeSeedSegment[10, #2, #3, #4, False]],
      2 #2]
    ] &, {RandomChoice[{False, True}, n], 
   RandomChoice[{\[Pi]/7, \[Pi]/8, \[Pi]/6}, n], 
   RandomInteger[{8, 14}, n], 
   RandomChoice[{Line, Polygon, BezierCurve, FilledCurve[BezierCurve[#]] &}, n]}]

Comment: hi, Did you see my last message, can you enter the code that I left you?

Comment: zeros, please see [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31780/125) for exporting to a multiple-page PDF.

Comment: hi ,Apparently you misunderstood me, my question was how to insert that piece of code in the program that you explained to me to generate multiple mandalas, if these remain uneven when exporting to pdf, I can somehow fix it by editing the pdf.
If you haven't gotten bored of me, I'd appreciate any help.